# Android alias for receiver

Tags: android, widget, android-manifest, receiver

We created a new folder structure for old code and we start having problems.

First with the launcher activity but it was fixed adding activity-alias option to manifest

Now the problem is the widget, when we update the application and the widget code (receiver) is on different folder so it wont work.

There is any option on manifest like the activity-alias as but for receivers?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the **name of a receiver changes** the device admin **will be disabled** when the application is updated. This also applies to other kinds of receivers, such as **App Widgets**.

[Things that cannot change](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) 
source: Android Developers Blog 06/2011

**update:** You could create an empty class that delegates the methods to the new class

```
public OldWidgetReceiverClass extends NewReceiverClass {}
```

Comment: Thank you I will do that